# False could not auto wire Intelli-J error

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea

### Problem

Hi, I have a project that works fine (`mvn clean install` and running).

However, intelli-J is complaining that there is an issue with the autowiring of a datasource:

> Could not autowire. There is more than one bean of `DataSource`type.

It seems however, that the actual beans themselves are part of the spring infrastructure.

Any ideas?

### Screenshots

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can read

> Could not autowire. There is more than one bean of DataSourcetype.

more than one bean are in your application context. In that case, you can specify explicitly which one you want to autowire with `@Qualifier("nameOfNeededBean")`. It's obviously an intellij issue.

Comment: This is a fake error actually. Everything works fine when you run the project using maven and spring boot.

Comment: maybe. But you've got two beans of the same type in the context. So I think it works only thankful some spring boot feature.